# jOOQ's field not converting {0} in SQL

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a jOOQ field declared like this (this is an over simplification):

```
field("INTERVAL '{0} minutes'", Duration.class, X)
```

I expected that to generate a Duration with X minutes that I could use in my queries, but instead it generated a duration of 0 minutes all the time. I inspected the generated SQL with `toString` and I saw instead of the expected `INTERVAL '30 minutes'` jOOQ generated `INTERVAL '{0} minutes'`, so, it's treating `{0}` as a literal instead of replacing it by the template variable.

This is how I tested, this:

```
using(configuration).select(field("INTERVAL '30 minutes'", Duration.class)).toString()
```

yields:

```
select INTERVAL '30 minutes'
```

Whereas this:

```
using(configuration).select(field("INTERVAL '{0} minutes'", Duration.class, 30)).toString()
```

yields:

```
select INTERVAL '{0} minutes'
```

Is there a workaround to this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've shown [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622175/521799), and as is documented for [jOOQ's plain SQL templating feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), the templates preprocess string literals (and comments, and some other things), to prevent modifying them.

[But you should never resort to concatenating strings with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/04/never-concatenate-strings-with-jooq/). There's always a better way. You could do it like this, for example:

```
field("INTERVAL {0}", Duration.class, DSL.inline(X + " minutes"))
```

I know. I'm still concatenating strings. But I'm doing that in a *"safe place"*, wrapped by `DSL.inline()` (or `DSL.val()`), which produce properly escaped literals (or bind variables). What I meant is there should never be a reason to concatenate the SQL fragment, even with plain SQL templating.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with this:

```
field("INTERVAL '" + X + " minutes'", Duration.class)
```

If you check the jOOQ documentation [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) you'll see this relevant part:

> When processing these plain SQL templates, a mini parser is run that handles things like
>
> - String literals
> - ...
>
> The above are recognised by the templating engine and contents inside of them are ignored when replacing numbered placeholders and/or bind variables.

So, according to the docs, it's expected that a `{0}` inside of quotes doesn't get replaced. But that was quite unexpected for the case of building Postgres intervals with jOOQ, where Postgres will just swallow that `{0}` and cause a bug that doesn't produce an exception, so there is no track of it:

```
# select interval '{0} minutes';

 interval 
----------
 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: [Nooo, don't concatenate strings with jOOQ, ever!](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/04/never-concatenate-strings-with-jooq/)